# (sequence .) . flip fmap === forM?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree, equational-reasoning

Is `(sequence .) . flip fmap` the same as `forM`? I ask here because [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) seems not to say the same...

Comment: I believe they are equivalent. AFAIK, pointfree.io does not guarantee the shortest option, or in general knows about all the library helpers.

Comment: Exactly; `(sequence .) . flip fmap` is *already* in point-free form. It's `pointfree.io`, not `minimalexpression.io`.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was point free already, but somehow I never tried putting already pointfree expression there, so I got convinced that it would shorten to the minimum. I don't even know if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
(sequence .) . flip fmap
(sequence .) . (\u f -> fmap f u)
\u -> sequence . (\f -> fmap f u)
\u f -> sequence (fmap f u)
\u f -> mapM f u
flip mapM
forM
```

[As chi notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197912/sequence-flip-fmap-form#comment117034173_66197912), presumably it's just that pointfree.io doesn't know about `forM`.